# How can I include C#, php, NodeJS, etc. in one website?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, php, node-js, c#

I'm wondering how I can include C#, PHP, NodeJS all in one website.

Are there servers that provide ways to use all 3, and possibly more (like WordPress)?

Maybe I need more than one server, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: What do you mean by server?  Are you talking about web server software or physical computers, or virtual private servers (VPS)?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller:  I really just need some way, like server software, to be able to support all of these different languages.  I'm basically trying to have all of these on one website.  I can put each of these on a separate webpage (in other words, one webpage won't have more than one language on it), but I need all of these on the same website.  Thank you ahead of time for any help you can provide!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by mixing languages like that? Generally speaking, picking *one* language for your server-side development makes everything easier (you don't need a development team that can deal with multiple languages, you don't have the complexity of getting them running at the same time, you can use built-in session handling without having to translate that between the different languages). You'd need a *really* good reason to mix them for the all the pain it will create.

Comment: @Quentin: I'm trying to create a portfolio of the work I've done towards earning my web design degree, but I've used many different languages for different classes.   I just didn't really consider what I would need out of a server until now.